# If A>=0 is a summable sequence, then A^2 is also summable

Tags: real-analysis

I was stuck on a homework problem.
Given sequence $A\geq 0$ is summable, prove $A^2$ is also summable.

I tried to bring out the definition and I obtained
$|A(1)+A(2)+\cdots +A(n)-L|<\epsilon$

I then tried to multiply it by $A(n_0)$ such that $A(n_0)=\operatorname{Min}\{A(1),A(2),\cdots ,A(n)\}.$

But now the problem aries, although we know

$A(1)A(n_0)+A(2)A(n_0)+\cdots +A(n)A(n_0)\leq (A(1))^2+(A(2))^2+\cdots +(A(n))^2$

We still do not have 
$|A(1)A(n_0)+A(2)A(n_0)+\cdots +A(n)A(n_0)-LA(n_0)|\leq |(A(1))^2+(A(2))^2+\cdots +(A(n))^2-LA(n_0)| <\epsilon$

I appreciate any hints or suggestions. Please do not post solutions please.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $A$ is summable then from some point on $|A| <1$. That means that $A^2 < |A|$.